# How can I check the syntax of Python script without executing it?

Tags: python, compilation, syntax-checking

I used to use `perl -c programfile` to check the syntax of a Perl program and then exit without executing it. Is there an equivalent way to do this for a Python script?

Answer (score 741, accepted):

You can check the syntax by compiling it:

```
python -m py_compile script.py
```

Comment: `import script`, but all code must be in functions. Which is good practice anyway. I've even adopted this for shell scripts. From here it's a small step to unit testing.

Comment: won't work if you have an embedded engine with injected modules

Comment: `python -m compileall` can also do directories recursively and has a better command line interface.

Comment: Great answer, but how can I prevent it for creating ".pyc" file? What's the use of ".pyc" file by the way?

Comment: @MarkJohnson: So if `mycode.pyc` file exist the performance optimization is obtained even when we run `python mycode.py`, am I right?

Comment: Anyone can tell me how this command work? When I tried for this code: `print time.timezone` (without `import time`), there was no message at all after I run the command.

Comment: For Python 2.7.9, when `-m py_compile` is present, I'm finding that neither `-B` nor  `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` suppresses creation of the **.pyc** file.

Comment: @C2H5OH: compileall ignores sources not ending with ".py" and I could not work it around.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that using this method, python will return a non-zero exit status of the code compile fails.  So you can incorporate this into a build script if you like.

Comment: I cursed python for *years* due to my script failing due to a syntax error in the exception handler print statement....this should be the second thing taught after teaching the interactive mode.

Comment: What's the output after running this command? I don't see any *.pyc files generated. If nothing is returned, does that mean my syntax is fine?

Comment: I run the script `python -m py_compile src/nike_run.py`, and it finished without error msg, but the code will crash in running time with a message 'TypeError: run_test_in_batch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'total_test_rownum'', seems it can not detect such error. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: @Ninja Correct. Python is a dynamic language, so type errors are detected at runtime.

Comment: Thank you @Jasper-M. Could you suggest one tool to check syntax? I know one of them is PyCharm, but it's too heavy for only syntax check.

Comment: this answer is not correct, as it can lead to false positives: for example python3 compile successful with try catch block of a `StandardError` and that has been removed in python 3. So be cautious....

Comment: @Ninja your main problem is that you shouldn't really do a static code analysis of a dynamic programming language (like Python) without having an engine that parses and/or executes the code, to provide you with a list of possible errors, which would occur at run-time. PyCharm doesn't just perform "only syntax check" but actually parses python code with an internal engine and that's why it's "too heavy".

Comment: @C2H5OH great answer. The CLI is really nice, too. +1

Answer (score 71):

You can use these tools:

- [PyChecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/)
- [Pyflakes](https://github.com/pyflakes/pyflakes)
- [Pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857)

Comment: All of these do much more than check the syntax. Really this isn't the answer.

Comment: All of these check the syntax, so the answer is correct. Other checks are a (very useful) bonus.

Comment: PyChecker hasn't been updated since 2011 and does not support Python 3.

Comment: Pylint is very customizable.  I used to add disable directives all over my code for Pylint, but lately I've been just setting up a pylintrc to turn off all the warnings I don't care about.  With the right pylintrc, this may well be the best answer.

Comment: Pyflakes was perfect

Answer (score 28):

```
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]
source = open(filename, 'r').read() + '\n'
compile(source, filename, 'exec')
```

Save this as checker.py and run `python checker.py yourpyfile.py`.

Comment: A little bit too heavy for a Makefile for a tiny script collection, but it does the job and doesn't produce any unwanted file.

Comment: It's an old answer, but something to notice is that this only checks the syntax, not if the script would successfully execute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Just one comment, there is no answer if the code is correct. Otherwise error messages with line numbers are shown.

Answer (score 27):

Here's another solution, using the `ast` module:

```
python -c "import ast; ast.parse(open('programfile').read())"
```

To do it cleanly from within a Python script:

```
import ast, traceback

filename = 'programfile'
with open(filename) as f:
    source = f.read()
valid = True
try:
    ast.parse(source)
except SyntaxError:
    valid = False
    traceback.print_exc()  # Remove to silence any errros
print(valid)
```

Comment: Awesome one-liner that does not require all of the imported libs or produce .pyc files. Thanks!

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Compiling these files (as the accepted answer suggests) is overkill, when one just wants to know if the syntax is valid.

Comment: Notice that `ast.parse(string)` is [equivalent to](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ast.py#L37) `compile(string, filename='<unknown>', mode='exec', flags=ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: This also does not execute top-level code. Python actually executes modules when compiling or importing them; it's just that "executing a `def` statement" is how Python creates function objects, which then become attributes of the module object.

Answer (score 26):

Pyflakes does what you ask, it just checks the syntax. From the docs:

> Pyflakes makes a simple promise: it will never complain about style, and it will try very, very hard to never emit false positives.
>
> Pyflakes is also faster than Pylint or Pychecker. This is largely because Pyflakes only examines the syntax tree of each file individually.

To install and use:

```
$ pip install pyflakes
$ pyflakes yourPyFile.py
```

Comment: This is better than most voted answer. It not only checks for syntax, but also shows all the unused and undefined variables. Very helpful especially when you are running time taking scripts.

Answer (score 15):

```bash
python -m compileall -q .
```

Will compile everything under current directory recursively, and print only errors.

```
$ python -m compileall --help
usage: compileall.py [-h] [-l] [-r RECURSION] [-f] [-q] [-b] [-d DESTDIR] [-x REGEXP] [-i FILE] [-j WORKERS] [--invalidation-mode {checked-hash,timestamp,unchecked-hash}] [FILE|DIR [FILE|DIR ...]]

Utilities to support installing Python libraries.

positional arguments:
  FILE|DIR              zero or more file and directory names to compile; if no arguments given, defaults to the equivalent of -l sys.path

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -l                    don't recurse into subdirectories
  -r RECURSION          control the maximum recursion level. if `-l` and `-r` options are specified, then `-r` takes precedence.
  -f                    force rebuild even if timestamps are up to date
  -q                    output only error messages; -qq will suppress the error messages as well.
  -b                    use legacy (pre-PEP3147) compiled file locations
  -d DESTDIR            directory to prepend to file paths for use in compile-time tracebacks and in runtime tracebacks in cases where the source file is unavailable
  -x REGEXP             skip files matching the regular expression; the regexp is searched for in the full path of each file considered for compilation
  -i FILE               add all the files and directories listed in FILE to the list considered for compilation; if "-", names are read from stdin
  -j WORKERS, --workers WORKERS
                        Run compileall concurrently
  --invalidation-mode {checked-hash,timestamp,unchecked-hash}
                        set .pyc invalidation mode; defaults to "checked-hash" if the SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH environment variable is set, and "timestamp" otherwise.
```

Exit value is 1 when syntax errors have been found.

Thanks [C2H5OH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100958/c2h5oh).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps useful online checker PEP8 : http://pep8online.com/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the above answers @Rosh Oxymoron. I improved the script to scan all files in a dir that are python files. So for us lazy folks just give it the directory and it will scan all the files in that directory that are python. you can specify any file ext. you like.

```
import sys
import glob, os

os.chdir(sys.argv[1])
for file in glob.glob("*.py"):
    source = open(file, 'r').read() + '\n'
    compile(source, file, 'exec')
```

`Save this as checker.py and run python checker.py ~/YOURDirectoryTOCHECK`

Answer (score 0):

for some reason (I am a py newbie ...) the -m call did not work ...

so here is a bash wrapper func ...

```bash
# ---------------------------------------------------------
# check the python synax for all the *.py files under the
# <<product_version_dir/sfw/python
# ---------------------------------------------------------
doCheckPythonSyntax(){

    doLog "DEBUG START doCheckPythonSyntax"

    test -z "$sleep_interval" || sleep "$sleep_interval"
    cd $product_version_dir/sfw/python
    # python3 -m compileall "$product_version_dir/sfw/python"

    # foreach *.py file ...
    while read -r f ; do \

        py_name_ext=$(basename $f)
        py_name=${py_name_ext%.*}

        doLog "python3 -c \"import $py_name\""
        # doLog "python3 -m py_compile $f"

        python3 -c "import $py_name"
        # python3 -m py_compile "$f"
        test $! -ne 0 && sleep 5

    done < <(find "$product_version_dir/sfw/python" -type f -name "*.py")

    doLog "DEBUG STOP  doCheckPythonSyntax"
}
# eof func doCheckPythonSyntax
```