# What to look after to decide if Python code is v2 or v3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python, and decided to install Anaconda and Python v3. When I try to run examples I find on-line, they often don't work even when unchanged. I assume that the reason is sometimes that I try to run a version 2 script. What are some easy markers to look for in the code to tell if that is the case?

Comment: This is very broad; you basically have to learn the differences between 2 / 3.

Comment: You could look for uses of `print` as a statement instead of a function.

Comment: The easiest marker for me is the `print` statement. If its a statement its Python 2 , if its a function its Python 3.

Comment: `print x` unambiguously identifies a script as Python 2, but `print(x)` doesn't unambiguously identify a script as Python 3, because it's valid syntax in both versions.

Comment: One thing that absolutely marks code as Python3 is function annotations. `def f(a: int, b: list) -> tuple: return (a,b)` will throw a syntax error in python 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way (I find) to identify if a script is created for Python 3 vs Python 2 is to try to find a print statement, if the print statement has parentheses around the argument your script is made for Python  3 if not, it is made for Python 2.

E.g.

Python 2 code would look like
`print "Hello World"`

Where Python 3 code would look like `print("Hello World")`

Comment: Yeah, ive been doing way too much C programming and its more of a habit. Ill just edit it out real fast.

Comment: As pointed out in a comment above, this is evidence, but not proof. So what else is there to look for?

Comment: Unless it's a `Python 2` code and the author used `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: Although this is acceptable as a crude metric, `print("Hello world")` is also valid in Python 2, even without `from __future__ import print_function` and is becoming the preferred expression for  those of us who are in some sort of transition from 2 to 3.

Comment: And as a remark, for simple scripts, it is easy to write code correct for both Python2 and Python3. So what would they be called ?

Answer (score 1):

http://python3porting.com/differences.html

This lists the major differences you see betwen python 2 and 3. Mainly functions have been deprecated or renamed.

Answer (score 1):

2to3 is a library which does the "translation" between both language versions. The documentation for the library lists the [changes it does to translate python 2 to python 3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) code.

The changed print, ne, dict and sys_exc are 4 differences I typically look at.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give an SO-valid answer:

Apart from checking shebang (if any), the only sure-proof way is try to compile it with both versions as per [How can I check the syntax of Python script without executing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284313/how-can-i-check-the-syntax-of-python-script-without-executing-it).