# Why doesn't Python spot errors before execution?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following code in Python:

```
a = "WelcomeToTheMachine"
if a == "DarkSideOfTheMoon":
    awersdfvsdvdcvd
print "done!"
```

Why doesn't this error? How does it even compile? In Java or C#, this would get spotted during compilation.

Comment: Here `a!="DarkSideOfTheMoon"`, so the body of the if condition never gets executed.

Comment: Related [How can I check the syntax of Python script without executing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4284313)

Comment: Because that isn't an error until execution.

Comment: What you have stumbled upon is the difference between syntax errors and runtime errors...

Comment: I suggest using a good IDE such as PyCharm to help you spot this kind of error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python isn't a compiled language, that's why your code doesn't throw compilation errors.

Python is a byte code interpreted language. Technically the source code gets "compiled" to byte code, but then the byte code is just in time (JIT) compiled if using PyPy or Pyston otherwise it's line by line interpreted.

The workflow is as follows :

**Your Python Code** -> **Compiler** -> **.pyc file** -> **Interpreter** -> **Your Output**

Using the standard python runtime What does all this mean? Essentially all the heavy work happens during runtime, unlike with C or C++ where the source code in it's entirety is analyzed and translated to binary at compile time.

Comment: It's a little compiled, and actual syntax errors are actually spotted during compilation. It's just that many things that would be part of the compilation phase in more static languages happen at runtime in Python.

Comment: Also, the standard implementation of Python doesn't do JIT. PyPy does JIT, but most people aren't using PyPy.

Comment: The "line by line interpreted" part is a figment of someone's imagination. By the time the cpython VM runs the bytecode, the "lines" are only line numbers retained for diagnostic purposes. As far as the VM is concerned, there are no lines. And the code doesn't "technically" get compiled. It very much gets compiled into a VM instruction stream, just as a C# or Java compiler would do! There is even an optimizer, and ongoing work on making the VM faster. No interpretation is taking place.

Answer (score 4):

During "compiling", python pretty much only checks your syntax.  Since `awersdfvsdvdcvd` *is* a valid identifier, no error is raised until that line actually gets executed.  Just because you use a name which wasn't defined doesn't mean that it couldn't have been defined elsewhere... e.g.:

```
globals()['awersdfvsdvdcvd'] = 1
```

earlier in the file would be enough to suppress the `NameError` that would occur if the line with the misspelled name was executed.

Ok, so can't python just look for globals statements as well?  The answer to that is again "no" -- From module "foo", I can add to the globals of module "bar" in similar ways.  And python has no way of knowing what modules are or will be imported until it's actually running (I can dynamically import modules at runtime too).

---

Note that most of the reasons that I'm mentioning for why Python as a language *can't* give you a warning about these things involve people doing crazy messed up things.  There are a number of tools which *will* warn you about these things (making the assumption that you aren't going to do stupid stuff like that).  My favorite is [`pylint`](https://www.pylint.org/), but just about any python linter should be able to warn you about undefined variables.  If you hook a linter up to your editor, most of the time you can catch these bugs before you ever actually run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Because Python is an interpreted language. This means that if Python's interpreter doesn't arrive to that line, it won't produce any error.

Comment: Python is compiled to byte code, so it actually goes over the whole source code beforehand. Python is compiled, and the byte code is usually interpreted.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing to spot: It's not an "error" as far as Python-the-language is concerned. You have a perfectly valid Python program. Python is a dynamic language, and the identifiers you're using get resolved at runtime.

An equivalent program written in C#, Java or C++ would be invalid, and thus the compilation would fail, since in all those languages the use of an undefined identifier is required to produce a diagnostic to the user (i.e. a compile-time error). In Python, it's simply not known whether that identifier is known or not at compile time. So the code is valid. Think of it this way: in Python, having the address of a construction site (a name) doesn't require the construction to have even started yet. What's important is that by the time you use the address (name) as if there was a building there, there better be a building or else an exception is raised :)

In Python, the following happens:

`a = "WelcomeToTheMachine"` looks up the enclosing context (here: the module context) for the attribute `a`, and sets the attribute `'a'` to the given string object stored in a pool of constants. It also caches the attribute reference so the subsequent accesses to `a` will be quicker.

`if a == "DarkSideOfTheMoon":` finds the `a` in the cache, and executes a binary comparison operator on object `a`. This ends up in `builtins.str.__eq__`. The value returned from this operator is used to control the program flow.

`awersdfvsdvdcvd` is an expression, whose value is the result of a lookup of the name `'awersdfvsdvdcvd'`. This expression is evaluted. In your case, the name is not found in the enclosing contexts, and the lookup raises the `NameError` exception.

This exception propagates to the matching exception handler. Since the handler is outside of all the nested code blocks in the current module, the `print` function never gets a chance of being called. The Python's built-in exception handler signals the error to the user. The interpreter (a misnomer!) instance has nothing more to do. Since the Python process doesn't try to do anything else after the interpreter instance is done, it terminates.

There's absolutely nothing that says that the program *will* cause a runtime error. For example, `awersdfvsdvdcvd` could be set in an enclosing scope before the module is executed, and then no runtime error would be raised. Python allows fine control over the lifetime of a module, and your code could inject the value for `awersdfvsdvdcvd` after the module has been compiled, but before it got executed. It takes just a few lines of fairly straightforward code to do that.

This is, in fact, one of the many dynamic programming techniques that get used in Python programs. Their judicious use makes possible the kinds of functionality that C++ will not natively get in decades or ever, and that are very cumbersome in both C# and Java. Of course, Python has a performance cost - nothing is free.

If you like to get such problems highlighted at compilation time, there are tools you can easily integrate in an IDE that would spot this problem. E.g. PyCharm has a built-in static checker, and this error would be highlighted with the red squiggly line as expected.