# Python Performance - for loops with method without looped variables

Tags: python

I have a doubt in performance and can't find how python behaves in each of these cases:

```
def something(object):
    if object== 'something':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Option 1:

```
def something_bigger(list, object):
    total= 0
    for item in list:
        total+= something(object)

def something_bigger2(list, object):
    total= 0
    for item in list:
        total-= something(object)
```

Option 2:

```
def something_bigger(list, object):
    total= 0
    something = something(object)
    for item in list:
        total+= something(object)

def something_bigger2(list, object):
    total= 0
    something = something(object)
    for item in list:
        total-= something(object)
```

The examples are simple and make no sense but my objective is to understand if python understands that **`something()returns always the same** and **doesn't repeat the if endless times**.

Option two, without understanding how python will do this, seems faster but on the other side I'm repeating my code!

Comment: That depends on the specific interpreter and how good it is at recognising and optimising these specific cases. Fundamentally you *are* telling Python to repeat the `if..else` every single time.

Comment: No, Python interpreter won't infer that it can avoid branching (because it _does not know_ that branching may be avoided). You know it, so write code accordingly.

Comment: So the best way is to call methods with imutable variables outside the for?

Comment: CPython don't optimize your code, PyPy and Pyston tries to do it. If you can avoid multiple `something` calls then do it.

Comment: Usually when in doubt about performance, you profile your code. Try cProfile ore line_profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Python is not compiled the way Java or C# applications (for example) are. A line of code is only evaluated right as it's executed.

This question I asked a few weeks ago can really detail one of the 
core differences in Python:
[Why doesn't Python spot errors before execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756081/why-doesnt-python-spot-errors-before-execution)

That's a different question, sure, but the jist is the same. Python doesn't even *know*  what the next instruction will be. C or C++, on the other hand, are compiled down to a list of assembly instructions.

That's why you need an interpreter to run the scripts.

What you're describing is branch prediction. There's a really excellent explanation on this famous question:

[Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array)

But Python doesn't compile down to assembly like C++ does. The instructions are not being fed to the CPU in a raw enough format to make branch prediction consistent. You have to detect that behavior yourself and correct it.